# Slick: How to neatly close resources and chain actions

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I wrote a small slick program today. it works. here is the code

```
package com.abhi

import slick.driver.MySQLDriver.api._
import slick.jdbc.meta.MTable
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Success, Failure}

object MySlickApp extends App {
   val db = Database.forConfig("essential-slick ")
   val messages = TableQuery[MessageTable]

   val tableExists = MTable.getTables map { tables =>
      tables.exists(_.name.name == messages.baseTableRow.tableName)
   }

   val dropAction = messages.schema.drop
   val createAction = messages.schema.create

   val freshMessages = Seq(
      Message("Dave", "Hello HAL. Do you read me? HAL?"),
      Message("HAL", "Affirmtive, Dave. I read you."),
      Message("Dave", "Open the pod doors, HAL."),
      Message("HAL", "I'm Sorry. Dave. I'm afraid, I cannot do that.")
   )

   val insertAction = messages ++= freshMessages

   val f5 = for {
      f1 <- db.run(tableExists)
      f2 <- db.run(dropAction) if f1 == true
      f3 <- db.run(createAction)
      f4 <- db.run(insertAction)
   } yield (f1, f2, f3, f4)

   f5.onComplete{
      case Success(s) => println("table initialized successfully "); db.close
      case Failure(f) => println(f.getMessage); db.close
   }
   scala.io.StdIn.readLine()
}

final case class Message (sender: String, content: String, id: Long = 0L)

final case class MessageTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Message](tag, "Message") {
   def id = column[Long]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
   def sender = column[String]("sender")
   def content = column[String]("content")
   def * = (sender, content, id) <> (Message.tupled, Message.unapply)
}
```

There are two things which I don't like about this program

1. I have to specify db.run on every line in the for comprehension. I tried to put all my actions in a Seq and then give the DBIO.seq to the db.run but it ran everything async rather than in order.
2. I have to call db.close in both "success" and "failure" scenarios. I wonder if there is a way in which I can close the resources in a single place without duplication.

Comment: For second clause you can combine `andThen()` and `onComplete()` for close db in a single place without duplication. Can you show your result in db for first clause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the latest slick 3.2
1. you can run it as a single db run this way by chaining the DBIOActions together instead of the futures. Doing it this way provides added the benefit of running it as a transaction as well:

```
val f = for {
     r1 <- tableExists
     r2 <- {
       if(r1){
             dropAction
          }else{ 
             DBIO.successful()
          }
        }
      r3 <- createAction
      r4 <- insertAction
   } yield (f)
db.run(f).transactionally
```

2. calling db.close: There really is no need to call db close. This doesn't close connections. Doing this shuts down your entire database setup / connection pooling etc). There is no mechanism for manually closing connections as slick already handled this for you inside the db.run call. 
   Since this is a "run once" program it doesn't really matter much either way. If this was running as a web service type of program any subsequent request to the service would never be able to connect to the database again!